# How to find the value of a column in R w.r.t maximum values in different columns in dataframe?

Tags: r, data-analysis

Suppose, I have one dataframe which contains the employee details.

Dataframe employee have following columns:

`Employee_Id`, `Employee_name`, `Employee_age`, `Employee_Salary`, `Employee_Experience`.

I want to find the name of employees which has maximum age, salary and experience using one command only, may be by using apply family function. Please help me if you know how I can do it ?

Comment: To make this a good question you should supply some sample data or use one of the built in sample data sets and show the desired results.  You should also explain what ideas you tried.  You may want to start by finding the way to get the results for one variable only.

Comment: it's highly unlikely that a single specific record has maximum value for each column

Comment: I am not saying that a single record have all the maximum values, I want to have individual employees with maximum value in one command.

Answer (score 1):

```
Employee_Id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Employee_name <- c('John', 'Sarah', 'David', 'Emma', 'Peter')
Employee_age <- c(22, 34, 40, 48, 55)
Employee_Salary <- c(2000, 3000, 5800, 3800, 5000)
Employee_Experience <- c(2, 12, 18, 26, 24)

employees <- data.frame(Employee_Id, Employee_name, Employee_age, Employee_Salary, Employee_Experience)

employees[employees$Employee_Salary == max(employees$Employee_Salary) | employees$Employee_age == max(employees$Employee_age) | employees$Employee_Experience == max(employees$Employee_Experience), c('Employee_name')]
```

Result:

[1] David Emma  Peter

Levels: David Emma John Peter Sarah

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data.frame is `dat`

```
 library(tidyverse)
    dat %>% filter(Employee_age==max(Employee_age),
                   Employee_Salary==max(Employee_Salary), 
                   Employee_Experience==max(Employee_Experience)) %>% 
      select(Employee_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know one liner but this logic would work for one column:
eg.

```
# for Employee salary
df[which(df$Employee_salary == max(df$Employee_salary))]
```

you can do same logic for others

Comment: This one I know and I have executed.